# PHP. $_SESSION['myString']. Но любая строка == 0. Почему?

Tags: php

Я в PHP очень плох, но есть задача и проблема. Задача не важна, а проблему я не могу понять.

Дано: login.php. Там в $_SESSION['email'] присваивается $myrow['email'] ($myrow['email'] == 'qwe@qwe.qwe', выводил через echo и там именно это значение, вбивал и другие, все хорошо).

```
$_SESSION['email'] = $myrow['email'];
```

Далее: cabinet.php, далее весь код (вывод одной строки), отображает только 0. Какая бы строка не передавалась в login.php в переменную $_SESSION['email'], всегда отображает 0.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo $_SESSION['email'] + '<br>';
?>
```

Мне необходимо получить в cabinet.php строку, которую я передаю в переменную $_SESSION['email'] в login.php.

P.S. Я неплохо знаю Java, и поэтому данная ситуация мне кажется багом в условиях именно моего компьютера (установки настройка денвера +- кривые руки, эх). Т.е. возможно написанные мной куски кода не дадут абсолютно  никакой информации. Если так, прошу указать в комментариях что еще необходимо указать, я обязательно поправлю свой вопрос.

P.P.S. `$_SESSION['id'] = $myrow['id'];` $myrow['id'] == 2, в cabinet.php `echo $_SESSION['id'];` $_SESSION['id'] == 2... а вот строка всегда равна 0.

Comment: Посмотрите настройки в php.ini, где хранятся сессии, возможно там криво настроено. Кстати вместо денвера на мой взгляд лучше что-то другое поставить, XAMPP например. С денвером в свое время помню тоже были постоянные проблемы подобного рода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В PHP оператор конкатенации строк - точка `.`. Знак `+` - именно арифметическое сложение.

Раз вы пытаетесь складывать два операнда, они будут приведены с числу. Строку, не начинающуюся с цифр, PHP приводит к нулю. `0 + 0 = 0`, вот этот ноль вам и выводится.

Comment: Вот почему я не люблю PHP. Это лично мое мнение. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

попробуй просто создать 2 файла, в обязательном порядке в каждом запустить сессию, (session_start()), и в одном файле записать данные в сессию:

```
$_SESSION['test'] = 'Тесттест';
```

А в другом файле - просто вывести это

```
 echo $_SESSION['test'];
```

Если не выведет во втором файле - значит проблема в сессиях, если выведет - пойдем дальше ловить ошибки

Answer (score 0):

28.05 ночью я задал вопрос, т.к. 2 часа не мог понять почему выводит 0 вместо строки. Я перезагружал denwer, запускал в разных браузерх, инкогнито, чистил куки и т.д. 28.05 утром я включил комп, запустил denwer и открыл проект. Все заработало без каких либо изменений. В общем для себя решил попробовать XAMPP как посоветовал mnv.